# Why Spring Boot Application is closing on start up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Logs

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/home/edry/idea-IC-192.6817.14/lib/idea_rt.jar=32975:/home/edry/idea-IC-192.6817.14/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
  :/home/edry/Descargas/Rent/target/classes:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.5/aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.4.5/HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.15.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.24.0-GA/javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.10/byte-buddy-1.10.10.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.1.3.Final/jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3/dom4j-2.1.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.3/txw2-2.3.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.11/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.26/snakeyaml-1.26.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.0/jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.0/jackson-annotations-2.11.0.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.0/jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.11.0/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.0.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.11.0/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.0.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.11.0/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.0.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.8.9/liquibase-core-3.8.9.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.18/mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.13.2/log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.2.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.2/log4j-api-2.13.2.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.30/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.35/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar
    :/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/3.0.3/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.35/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar:/home/edry/.m2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.5.0/hsqldb-2.5.0.jar com.rent.RentApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-05-20 08:07:56.507  INFO 18829 --- [           main] com.rent.RentApplication                 : Starting RentApplication on edry-Inspiron-3583 with PID 18829 (/home/edry/Descargas/Rent/target/classes started by edry in /home/edry/Descargas/Rent)
2020-05-20 08:07:56.512  INFO 18829 --- [           main] com.rent.RentApplication                 : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-05-20 08:07:57.766  INFO 18829 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-05-20 08:07:57.786  INFO 18829 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-20 08:07:58.294  INFO 18829 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-20 08:07:58.730  INFO 18829 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-20 08:08:00.867  INFO 18829 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM R_Renta.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2020-05-20 08:08:00.882  INFO 18829 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM R_Renta.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2020-05-20 08:08:00.890  INFO 18829 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT `LOCKED` FROM R_Renta.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
2020-05-20 08:08:00.932  INFO 18829 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock
2020-05-20 08:08:01.076  INFO 18829 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog    : Reading resource: db/changelog/20200519000000_initial.xml
2020-05-20 08:08:03.760  INFO 18829 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT MD5SUM FROM R_Renta.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
2020-05-20 08:08:03.761  INFO 18829 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM R_Renta.DATABASECHANGELOG
2020-05-20 08:08:03.762  INFO 18829 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from R_Renta.DATABASECHANGELOG
2020-05-20 08:08:03.762  INFO 18829 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM R_Renta.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2020-05-20 08:08:03.771  INFO 18829 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
2020-05-20 08:08:04.024  INFO 18829 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-20 08:08:04.129  INFO 18829 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
DB connection for DEV - H2
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3382/R_Renta
2020-05-20 08:08:04.301  INFO 18829 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-20 08:08:04.545  INFO 18829 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-05-20 08:08:04.547  INFO 18829 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-05-20 08:08:04.580  INFO 18829 --- [           main] com.rent.RentApplication                 : Started RentApplication in 8.877 seconds (JVM running for 9.367)
2020-05-20 08:08:04.730  INFO 18829 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-20 08:08:04.973  INFO 18829 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2020-05-20 08:08:05.410  INFO 18829 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-20 08:08:05.425  INFO 18829 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-20 08:09:05.436  INFO 18829 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-20 08:09:05.439  INFO 18829 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-20 08:09:05.440  INFO 18829 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-20 08:09:05.444  INFO 18829 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rent</groupId>
    <artifactId>Rent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Rent</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3382/R_Renta
spring.datasource.username=R_Renta
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create


spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/db.changelog-master.yaml

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.main.web-application-type=none

spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Try enabling debug logs and run again

Comment: You have packaging WAR and you are trying to start the main method?

Comment: You have an issue on the database connection. entitymanagerfactory causes to shutdown. Enable debug log and also check your database logs.

Comment: It is a project created with Spring Initializr and here is the log file

Comment: The problem was trying to configure liquibase on application.yml spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/Database
    username: root
    password: sfdsf

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect


  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/master.xml
    enabled: true

server:
  contextPath: /
  port: 8081

Answer (score 1):

`spring.main.web-application-type=none`

You have set your application to a non-web application. It will run as any other java programming, start, run anything e.g. scheduled tasks, beans implementing `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandlineRunner` will block i

Or if you want a web application that will run in a web container remove this property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was trying to configure liquibase on application.yml try this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/Database
    username: root
    password: sfdsf

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect


  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/master.xml
    enabled: true

server:
  contextPath: /
  port: 8081
```